# How to get drives, folders, or files in async way with .NET 4.5 or later?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, user-controls

#### EDITED

I designed a WPF UserControl, which is used to listing drives. However, some of drives are network storages (such as NAS) and might be in sleep mode. And then access those drives are very slowly (the response time is over 10 seconds in the first time). Therefore, I want my UserControl to display a progress bar or something else to notice the user "I'm not crashed", rather than let them wait the GUI response for 10 seconds.

According to @TheGeneral's suggestion, I use async/await for my solution, the code looks like:

```
private async Task refreshDriveAsync()
{
    DriveInfo[] drives = await Task.Run(() => DriveInfo.GetDrives());
    //do my stuff here
}
```

And the caller looks like:

```
//void is not good, but there's no error handling, so it's might ok here
public async void Refresh()
{
    //some stuff
    await refreshDriveAsync();
    //some more stuff
}
```

After the UserControl shown, it should call `Refresh()` once. So I wrote a part of code like this:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    Window w = this.GetParentWindow();    //my own extension method
    if (window != null)
        window.Loaded += ((t, e) => Refresh());
}
```

My expect result is: 
1. The window is shown.
2. My user control is not ready, but I can show a notification.
3. After 10 seconds, the user control get the drives, and refresh it's content.

However, the real world is:
1. The window is shown, but without any UI elements.
2. After 10 seconds, all UI elements shown, including my user control.

Any suggestion for this situation, please?

Comment: just *offload* it to a task run and `await` that

Answer (score 0):

Just *offload* it to a `Task.Run` and `await` that.

```
var drives = await Task.Run(() => DriveInfo.GetDrives());
```

Basically this will offload the workload to a thread-pool thread and create a *continuation* on the UI context. There are other ways to do this, however this will free up the UI (at the expense of a thread-pool thread)

Comment: I tried this solution, the window shown without any UI element and stuck 10 seconds. All of the UI elements (including my Usercontrol) shown in 10 seconds later. I'll modify my question to describe it more detailed.

Comment: @J.C: You mention a progress bar. Is your code flooding the UI thread with progress updates, to the point that it stays too busy to redraw the screen?

Comment: @StephenCleary, No, in fact, I'm not add the progress bar in current version.

Comment: @J.C: Please update your question with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).